# Blank parargraph HTML elements not shown

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Is there a way to get the browser to show a paragraph element even if it is empty?**

I am finding that if a p element has no text in it then the browser doesn't show it.

I know that this is probably a good thing most times, **but I am parsing & displaying HTML2 code from people who are using HTML badly(using blank p elements as vertical spacers instead of br elements)** so I have a need to show these blank paragraph elements to get the display the same as on the users old version.

Is there a CSS setting or HTML setting that will make the browser draw/show blank paragraph elements? Maybe I need to set the HTML DTD?

Comment: Maybe something like setting a width & height and using `display:block`?

Comment: Since you mentioned you are already parsing it, couldn't you just replace all blank paragraph elements with a <br /> or something like this? I don't know of a way that you could trust for every browser that'll do what you want otherwise but maybe there is some css hint or something.

Comment: Just a side comment: using `<br>`s as vertical spacers isn't much better than using `<p>`s.

Comment: @Juhana: really? :P lol what should I use then?

Comment: Ideally you would set the bottom margin of the previous element and/or the top margin of the next element to what you want, but if you really want an empty spacer element you could use an empty div that has the `height` attribute set to how much empty space you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-height:1em`. See http://jsfiddle.net/kcU5R/ for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

If it has no text inside, the height of the element is set to ZERO. That is why it disapears. You will have to style it so that it occupies the space you intend, or add an `&nbsp;` inside it.

You can set the min-height of the p element, to 1em, so that it has the height of one line of text.

Comment: It'd be polite to add a note that you edited your answer with the `min-height` only after I'd given the exact same answer... Just sayin'.

Comment: I didn't see your answer, before hiting submit button. I didn't even see that message about new answers that SO shows when a new answer is posted. Things are not instantaneous. We just had the same idea, at the same time, it happens all the time here on SO. =)